# Angular HttpClient Delete

Tags: angular, components, httpclient

I try to delete data from my database with an `HttpClient` (Angular), indeed I use a service (`MemberService`) which contain the `delete` method.

There is my MemberService :

```
export class MemberService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMembers(): Observable<IMember[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMember[]>('http://localhost:50867/api/Member');
  }

  getMember(memberId) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:50867/api/Member/' + memberId);
  }

  deleteMember(memberId) {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:50867/api/Member/' + memberId);
  }
}
```

So when i click on a button in my component.html that delete the data.

There is my component.ts code :

```
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public member$: Object ;
  private id$: Object;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _memberService: MemberService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.member$ = params.id );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id$ = this.member$;
    this._memberService.getMember(this.member$).subscribe(
      data => this.member$ = data);

  }

  deleteMember() {
    this._memberService.deleteMember(this.id$);
  }

}
```

There is my component.html :

```
<h1>{{ member$.username }}</h1>

<ul>
  <li><strong>wow:</strong> {{ member$.username }}</li>
  <li><strong>Email:</strong> {{ member$.emailUser }}</li>
  <li><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ member$.userPwd }}</li>
  <button (click)="deleteMember()">Delete</button>
</ul>
```

So when i launch my app and i click on the button, the id member is correct but nothing happens (there is no error in the console).
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: If you don't subscribe the http call is not fired. That's why you don't get anything. Your request is not getting fired. If you open the network in the inspector you wont see that request even starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `component.ts`, you have to `subscribe` in your `deleteMember` function like this :

```
deleteMember() {
  this._memberService.deleteMember(this.id$).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank that perform ;)